# org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=null] was not of the specified subclass

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have data model like below

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorColumn;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorType;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.DiscriminatorOptions;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Entity
@Table
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="DTYPE", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@DiscriminatorValue("0")
@DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)
public class Employee implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Employee() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private int empID;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private Integer age;

    private String email;

    private String city;

    private String phNum;


    public String getPhNum() {
        return phNum;
    }

    public void setPhNum(String phNum) {
        this.phNum = phNum;
    }

    public int getEmpID() {
        return empID;
    }

    public void setEmpID(int empID) {
        this.empID = empID;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

}
```

Patient.java

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.DiscriminatorOptions;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Entity
@Table
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
@DiscriminatorValue("6")

public class Patient extends Employee {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotEmpty(message = "DOJ cannot be null")
    private String doj;

    private String primaryDoctor;


    public String getPrimaryDoctor() {
        return primaryDoctor;
    }

    public void setPrimaryDoctor(String primaryDoctor) {
        this.primaryDoctor = primaryDoctor;
    }

    public String getDoj() {
        return doj;
    }

    public void setDoj(String doj) {
        this.doj = doj;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "patient", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Encounter> encounterList;

    public List<Encounter> getEncounterList() {
        return encounterList;
    }

    public void setEncounterList(List<Encounter> encounterList) {
        this.encounterList = encounterList;
    }

}
```

Hibernate query at runtime

```
select useraccoun0_.empID as empID1_13_2_, useraccoun0_.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMPLOYEE6_13_2_, 
useraccoun0_.fullName as fullName2_13_2_, useraccoun0_.password as password3_13_2_, 
useraccoun0_.role as role4_13_2_, useraccoun0_.userName as userName5_13_2_, 
employee1_.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMPLOYEE2_2_0_, employee1_.age as age3_2_0_,
 employee1_.city as city4_2_0_, employee1_.email as email5_2_0_, employee1_.firstName as firstNam6_2_0_,
  employee1_.lastName as lastName7_2_0_, employee1_.phNum as phNum8_2_0_, employee1_4_.doj as doj1_11_0_,
   employee1_4_.primaryDoctor as primaryD2_11_0_, employee1_5_.specialization as speciali1_0_0_,
     employee1_.DTYPE as DTYPE1_2_0_, encounterl2_.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMPLOYEE4_3_4_, 
     encounterl2_.EID as EID1_3_4_, encounterl2_.EID as EID1_3_1_, encounterl2_.labTest_testID as labTest_2_3_1_,
      encounterl2_.medication_mid as medicati3_3_1_, encounterl2_.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMPLOYEE4_3_1_,
       encounterl2_.vitalSign_EID as vitalSig5_3_1_ from UserAccount useraccoun0_ 
        left outer join Employee employee1_ on useraccoun0_.EMPLOYEE_ID=employee1_.EMPLOYEE_ID
         left outer join Pharmacist employee1_1_ on employee1_.EMPLOYEE_ID=employee1_1_.EMPLOYEE_ID 
         left outer join Nurse employee1_2_ on employee1_.EMPLOYEE_ID=employee1_2_.EMPLOYEE_ID 
         left outer join LabAssistant employee1_3_ on employee1_.EMPLOYEE_ID=employee1_3_.EMPLOYEE_ID 
         left outer join Patient employee1_4_ on employee1_.EMPLOYEE_ID=employee1_4_.EMPLOYEE_ID 
         left outer join Doctor employee1_5_ on employee1_.EMPLOYEE_ID=employee1_5_.EMPLOYEE_ID 
         left outer join Encounter encounterl2_ on employee1_.EMPLOYEE_ID=encounterl2_.EMPLOYEE_ID
          where useraccoun0_.empID=4
```

In this query Discriminator column(DTYPE) is coming and its value is coming as 6. But it is giving me below exception

> org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=null] was not of the specified subclass [com.*.*.Employee]: the class of the given object did not match the class of persistent copy

So not sure why it is giving me this exception and why id is coming as null.